# event.preventDefault() working in Chrome, not Firefox for a submit button

Tags: jquery

I have the following submit button:

```
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Send" class="mybutton" />
```

When I use the following code

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").submit(function(){
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log('test');
        }
});
```

My page is refreshing in Firefox, but not Chrome. Can anyone point me in the right direction?

I would like to use the submit button for a jQuery .ajax call (not a regular form submit)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You need make sure you add `event` to the parameter list of the event function.  I think some browsers have a global `event`, that's why it works in some browsers.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#submit").submit(function(event){  // The event is passed to this function
      event.preventDefault();
      console.log('test');
   }
});
```

Comment: +1 The only answer which places `event` at the correct place :p

Comment: Great minds... I'm pretty new at coding. The event should be passed on submit, not on doc ready, correct?

Comment: The global `event` object (`window.event`) was a Microsoft thing. Chrome throws a bone to code that was written for IE. Firefox doesn't. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: How does `window.event` work if multiple events are fired at the same time?

Comment: @dyelawn: Correct. You want the submit `event`. There is no `event` associated with the `ready` function (it does pass an argument to the function you provide, but that argument is a reference to the `jQuery` object).

Comment: @Rocket: JavaScript on browsers is single-threaded (other than [web workers](http://www.w3.org/TR/workers/)). So multiple events can't be raised at the same time. I'm not saying it wasn't a dumb move anyway, but that's why it was even possible. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Oh.  So `window.event` just kept changing based on the last event that was triggered?  Oh man, that must have made for some fun debugging, I don't want to imagine that =/

Comment: @Rocket: Yup. Brilliant design, no? But we have to remember that *at the time*, this was a major step forward over the old `onclick` style of event handlers. (Microsoft created the concept behind DOM2 handlers, even though when DOM2 actually happened, the semantics were slightly different and it took Microsoft forever -- IE9! -- to get around to implementing the standard vs. their earlier innovation.)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder so IE9 does send the event to the function AND **ALSO** update window.event? http://jsbin.com/erejoh/52/edit

Comment: @RoyiNamir: Yes, provided you hook it up with DOM2 methods: http://jsbin.com/erejoh/53 So does Chrome.

Answer (score 7):

Have you tried passing the event through as a variable?

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#submit").submit(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();
            console.log('test');
    }
 });
```

Comment: This answer has my vote for using a different variable name than event, to show that it's not really necessary to call it event.

Comment: @Dismissile: Agreed, you can name it whatever you like :)

Answer (score 3):

Pass the event parameter in the function callback Try this

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log('test');
        }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Simply in the function onclick for the submit button write down like this

```
onclick="return myfunction();"
```

and inside the function statements

```
myfunction () {
return false;};
```

Answer (score 0):

You did not add the event to the function parameters.
fixed version:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submit").submit(function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                console.log('test');
        }
});
```

Comment: @Rocket, fixed allready, Thanks, I saw I wasn't the only one, He copied from me... =) lol