# Does Video.js support HLS with Flash fallback?

Tags: video.js

Does Video.js currently support HLS video with a Flash fallback. I'm getting mixed messages between the answers here and [documentation on Zencoder's website](https://app.zencoder.com/docs/guides/encoding-settings/using-instant-play#playback) which I believe is part of the same family of products.

I'm currently getting an error when trying to play HLS in Chrome and Firefox and would like to know if it is an implementation error on my part or if it is not supported and Zencoder's documentation is incorrect.

If it is not currently supported, is there a timeline? The [latest answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13867969/some-general-doubts-about-video-js/13886534#13886534) from December said it was coming soon, is that still the case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The short answer is it's still in progress, and the Zencoder docs shouldn't say that yet.

Email help at zencoder to get more info on it.