# How to add Ajax capabilites to Symfony

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony

I have a set of sessions in a page, which I want to remove using AJAX. i.e click on a link, and without having to navigate for a new page, just remove the session, and show a message on success.

Now, as per the given answer (*which still did not work for me*), I have the following:

**Controller**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;
//..

public function ajaxRemoveSessionAction()
{
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $session->remove('name');

    return new JsonResponse(array('success' => true));
}
```

**routing:**

```
ajax_remove_session:
    pattern:  /remove-session
    defaults: { _controller: FooTestBundle:Page:ajaxRemoveSession }
```

**twig:**

```
<a href="#" id="remove_session">Remove session</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#remove_session').click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
          url: {{ url('ajax_remove_session') }},
          cache: false,
          success: function(result){
             $(".success").append(result);
          }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

---

## **UPDATING QUESTION:**

With all the codes found in the the routing, controller and template

---

> Controller: PageController.php

/src/Simon/TestBundle/Controller/PageController.php

```
<?php

namespace Simon\TestBundle\Controller;

use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Session\Session;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;


class PageController extends Controller
{
    public function helloAction($name)
    {


        $session = new Session();
        $session->start();

        $session->get('name', 'Drak');
        $session->get('name');

        $session->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Profile Updated');

        $messages = null;

        foreach($session->getFlashBag()->get('notice', array()) as $message){
            $messages = $message;
        }


        return $this->render('SimonTestBundle:Page:index.html.twig', array('name' => $name.' '.$messages));
    }


    public function ajaxRemoveSessionAction()
    {
        // Destroy the desired session
        $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
        $session->remove('name');

        return new JsonResponse(array('success' => true));
    }
}
```

> Template: Twig template

/src/Simon/TestBundle/Resources/views/Page/index.html.twig

```
{% extends 'SimonTestBundle::layout.html.twig' %}

{% block body %}
    <a href="#" id="remove_session">Remove session</a>



    <script type="text/javascript">
        $('#remove_session').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

                $.ajax({
                    url: {{ url('ajax_remove_session') }},
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html){
                        // do something on success
                    }
                }).fail(function(event){
                            console.log(event);
                        });
            });
        });
    </script>



{% endblock %}
```

> Routing:

/src/Simon/TestBundle/Resources/config/routing.yml

```
simon_test_homepage:
    pattern:  /hello/{name}
    defaults: { _controller: SimonTestBundle:Page:hello }

ajax_remove_session:
    pattern:  /remove-session
    defaults: { _controller: SimonTestBundle:Page:ajaxRemoveSession }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to put the value of the URL's option between quotes :

```
url: '{{ url('ajax_remove_session') }}',
```

Comment: I did that. And navigated to `http://127.0.0.1/symfony/web/app_dev.php/hello/testing#` and I can see an error in the console saying `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }     testing:54` does this make any sense?

Comment: Can you update your question with the rendered HTML / JS of your page please ?

Comment: Here is the screenshot I am getting. http://imm.io/1iy9l and here is a pastbin of my base HTML/Twig template. http://pastebin.com/TwQqg8X0 so, maybe the problem could be from the base template too

Comment: see my second answer which solves `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token } ` issue.

Comment: Yeah, I have adjusted it. But it seems the problem was not from this error, to begin with

Answer (score 4):

**Example controller:**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;


public function ajaxRemoveSessionAction()
{
    // Destroy the desired session
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $session->remove('name');

    return new JsonResponse(array('success' => true));
}
```

**Example routing:**

```
ajax_remove_session:
    pattern:  /remove-session
    defaults: { _controller: FooTestBundle:Page:ajaxRemoveSession }
```

**Example twig:**

```
<a href="#" id="remove_session">Remove session</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#remove_session').click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
          url: {{ url('ajax_remove_session') }},
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
            // do something on success
          }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

These are just examples need testing.

Comment: I can't test it now, but if this works, I will give it `+50` bounty

Comment: Hi, I tried you code just now, because I was out. Anyway, I am hopping that upon a user's click on the link, I would like a message response to come from `ajaxRemoveSessionAction` saying, 'SESSION removed', I added inside the jquery, where it says `// do something on success` a simple alert message, and when I click on the link, nothing gets displayed. Only, the anchor `#` gets appended to the URL.

Comment: @Xlaltra did you include jquery library before the jquery code?

Comment: Yes, jQuery it loaded, I am still trying it. I don't know much about jQuery so, I can't tell if there is some typo in your script. I did `alert('sucess')` inside the query code, but it does not show anything. I really need help with this. Thank you for your interest

Comment: what browser do you test it on?

Comment: I am using Chrome, but the result is the same for all browsers.

Answer (score 1):

In your AJAX call you use global `event` object, which is not cross-browser and shouldn't be used (e.g. Firefox doesn't have it).

Pass event in function call instead:

```
$('#remove_session').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();

    // rest of your code
});
```

If you do it that way, jQuery takes care about cross-browser normalization and proper behaviour.

See also [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8838635/event-preventdefault-working-in-chrome-not-firefox-for-a-submit-button) to learn more about difference between global `event` object and event passed into function.

---

**If it still doesn't work**

- open developer tools in Chrome (F12)
- check in your console (*Console* tab) if there are any error reports after you click a button
- also, open *Network* tab and see if after clicking a button any request is made; what is response status?
- make sure your controller works with GET requests (as you don't specify request type, and `GET` is default)
- you may also try adding `dataType: "json"` to your AJAX request, but this shouldn't be a problem as Symfony's `JsonResponse` should already provide neccessary response headers

---

**Check other places**

- error you posted says where the unexpected `:` is; investigate that line; is the code you have posted here the `whole` javascript that you have on your page?

Comment: Yeah, I tried this, but to no avail. Doesn't seem to do anything. I am convinced there is something wrong with my approach.

Comment: it may be related to what `{{ url('ajax_remove_session') }}` is resolved to. I don't have experience with Symfony, but the steps I've provided in my edited answer should help to investigate which data is incorrect.

Comment: Well, I don't know what to think anymore. I just hope, I get an answer anyhow

Comment: *Never* give up. Debug.
Did you try the steps I've provided?
Please provide public address of your site, this may help *a lot*.

Comment: I am using a localhost, and I have tried your approach. But, I am not getting any results, this is what my controller is entirely made of http://pastebin.com/8egWHzDa I don't know what it wrong,

Comment: Don't you see *any* errors in *Console* or *Network* tab? 
Again, please provide public address. Without this not much more can be achieved towards solution.

Comment: I wish I could, but can't put it online now. Not that I don't want to, but I can't. But, the error I am getting in the console is this:  http://imm.io/1ixON I thought this might be a simple problem, but I guess it must be more than that.

Comment: update your question with links to full version of: routing configuration, html/js and controller code.

Comment: Done! Let me know, if you want more detail pls. and thank you

Answer (score 1):

After your comment to @Laurent Wartel's answer, I assume now you get `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token }`. Now it's clear, you have additional parentheses on end of your `click()` function.

In addition, you don't wait for document to load before binding `click()` event.
Because of this, jQuery tries to bind event to element that wasn't yet rendered. This is a common pitfall.

To run your code *after* page loads, you have to wrap it info `$(function() { ... }`.
Please, read full explanation [here](http://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/) as this is basic, yet very important.

To sum up, correct code is as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(function() {
        $('#remove_session').click(function(e){
            e.preventDefault();

            $.ajax({
                url: '{{ url('ajax_remove_session') }}',
                cache: false,
                success: function(html){
                    // do something on success
                }
            }).fail(function(event){
                        console.log(event);
                    });
        });
    });
</script>
```

It seems like somehow you've deleted that line during debugging, because *it is there* in your original question, but is not present in [source code](http://pastebin.com/qSRsnANG) you've sent later.

Comment: I have removed that line, as you asked, but the error still remain, and I don't think `Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token :` was referring to that, but I've removed it,

Comment: just to be sure: quotes around `{{ url('ajax_remove_session') }}` are also neccessary, I've corrected that. Make sure you also correct that in your script.

Comment: Done! But, I am thinking there is something horribly wrong with my controller! I'm not sure, if I am a noob to this, but the logic does not seem quite right to me. Do you think, the controller is ok?

Comment: If it still doesn't work, right click on your page, select 'show source...', paste all the source to pastebin.com and give us the link. Also write if there are any new errors.

Comment: This is the only code, I can see, when I see the source code. http://pastebin.com/qSRsnANG

Comment: Yes, I believe so. Because I can see `{"success":true}` I think you may solve the problem :)

Comment: `{"success":true}` is a valid JSON response from your controller. 
Your AJAX  code is correct and requests valid URL. 
Everything should work just fine now :) is that true?

Comment: Not at all. I am saying, if I navigate (copy-paste) that url into my browser, I will be greeted with that message. But, if I press the `remove session` nothing happens. I don't get any response, the session is not removed, everything stays as is. That is what the question is all about :)

Comment: OMG, I've read your code once again and I know what the error is. I will update my answer in a minute.

Comment: No, it's not what you think. The `<script>` tag is at the end of the body, and jQuery is included into the `<head>` tag. So the script is loaded after the DOM.

Comment: @MichałRybak Nope, I place jQuery at the bottom of my script, still the same problem. Nothing changes. I guess that was not it. I even remember using the document.onload function two days ago, but I simpliefied the script to get/understand the problem clearly.

Comment: I prefer to *ensure* everything is loaded instead of guessing if the little fact that both `<script>` and `<a>` elements are in the same '<section>` element matters or not. If you're working on the DOM, work on *complete* DOM.

Comment: I am sure, my controller is not right, I just can't tell what is wrong with it. @LaurentWartel I hope one, from the two of you takes this bounty :)

Comment: The code in http://pastebin.com/qSRsnANG WORKS FINE, it makes the Ajax call to `http://127.0.0.1/symfony/web/app_dev.php/remove-session`. Please verify that this URL gives a response on your side.

Comment: @Xlaltra, placing jQuery somewhere else is not what I suggested. Please provide link to the current version of your source code (right click -> show source).

Comment: @Laurent Wartel, he's opened it in the browser and got the right response (mentioned it above), so URL is ok. This is weird.

Comment: @LaurentWartel I can confirm that `{"success":true}` is what I get, on a blank white page, when I paste and follow that URL.

Comment: @MichałRybak Ok, there is no change to the source code, since the last time I gave you, except I've placed jQuery at the footer this time. as you can see http://pastebin.com/RKqLTPuE here

Comment: Can anyone just pastbin a simple controller/routing/twig script, that actually does remove a session? that would be one way to fix this problem, if I can just see a working example.

Comment: It's the opposite that should be done : keep the JQuery include in your `<head>` tag. http://pastebin.com/RKqLTPuE gives the error that you actually use JQuery functions before including the library.

Comment: Take a look at [this fiddle (updated)](http://jsfiddle.net/kG6wS/2/) - it uses your js code and makes a proper request.

Comment: Your controller code is functionnal, and removes the 'name' variable from your session. If you want to destroy the whole session, use `$this->get('session')->clear();`

Comment: To ensure: your ajax call now works, and only failure is that session doesn't get removed? If so, follow @Laurent Wartel, I don't have experience with Symfony, although your original code `$session->remove(...)` definitely *should* work.

Comment: Ok, jQuery kept inside the header, I just checked Michał Rybak's , code and saw the console. and I am getting response,  and I have changed `$session->remove('name');` from the controller to `$this->get('session')->clear();` If I check in the Network tab, when I click on the session remove tab, I can see a GET request with 200/ok status code, and the URI is `http://127.0.0.1/symfony/web/app_dev.php/remove-session?_=1381932520116` Now, the problem is that, the session is not getting removed, and I should be able to get the message that says 'OK' instead of everything standing still.

Comment: Where do you check if your session is removed ?

Comment: You don't get message back because there is only `// do something bla bla` comment in your AJAX `success` callback function.
How do you determine that session isn't removed? 
I advice to put `var_dump($session->get('name'));` right after clearing the session, then open `http://127.0.0.1/symfony/web/app_dev.php/remove-session?_=1381932520116` in browser and see what the output is.

Comment: I added this line in twig `<a href="#" id="remove_session">remove session {{ name }}</a>` so that name shows me the session that is created in the controller file (if you take a look at my question) that session setter line looks like `$session->getFlashBag()->add('notice', 'Profile Updated');` Or i'm not sure if that is how the session is set, but I see this link `remove session what Profile Updated` not changing at all, because, "remove session" is the plan text, but 'profile Update' is the session, which should be removed when I click in that link imo @LaurentWartel

Comment: @MichałRybak I know I am acting like a question vampire, but how do I display that json 'OK' message, when the link is clicked, so that will tell, me at-least some part of the script is working.

Comment: You can't verify if your session is detroyed on your homePage, since you create a new one each time in this action !

Comment: This is why I suggested testing `var_dump` on `remove session` page, but @Xlaltra doesn't seem to follow that.

Comment: @LaurentWartel But, the action the AJAX follows is the one that destroys the session. If I was reloading the the action which sets the session, then yes, I could say I am doing it wrong, but I believe AJAX is not invoking the controller which controller the session setter

Comment: Even if you destroy the session, the page **won't change without refresh** as it is already generated by PHP. PHP is server side. So if you expect that after destroying session via AJAX call, the value on page would magically change, you won't get it this way.

Comment: So what's the problem ? I think there is something wrong with your architecture. You need to define what you want to do, where, and when. I don't see any problem left regarding the question. The behavior you have is what it should be expected.

Comment: @LaurentWartel OK. in a nut shell. All, I want is: When I click the "remove session" link, I want the session to get removed, and I want to get a message, "OK" without having to be redirected. *it is as simple as that* that is what this whole thing is about

Comment: Simply use `if(html == '{"success":true}') { alert('OK'); }` instead of `// do something on success` and you will easily know that your session is destroyed. You can also use `if(html == '{"success":true}') { $('#remove_session').text('Session removed'); }`

Comment: @MichałRybak Well, I hope the above makes sense, if it is not possible to do in AJAX, then I guess, I'm screwed. btw: I am not trying to refresh the page, in-fact, the opposite is true. I am only trying to remove the session, and get a confirmation message, without having to refresh the page

Comment: You already have this. Just put `alert("OK")` in `success` function in your AJAX request: [link](http://pastebin.com/sU7BkN8p)

Comment: @LaurentWartel I did as you asked, http://pastebin.com/cpfcX0dv not sure what I am forgetting, because I am not getting the alert, and neither is the session getting destroyed. (But, lets leave out the session part for now)

Comment: @MichałRybak Ok, I can confirm that worked, I get the OK message, now can you shed light as to how to remove the session, and we can get done with this question?

Comment: @Xlaltra, session **is** destroyed. What proof do you need for that? Why do you assume that it isn't destroyed?

Comment: If you want to remove the link, replace `alert('OK')` with `$('#remove_session').replaceWith('<p>Session removed</p>');`

Comment: @Laurent - indeed, but I think OP doesn't understand fully the server-side/client-side difference. What we should do is try to explain this, because this is very important basis of all further web programming.
@Xlaltra, if you'll provide me with code of `layout.html.twig` I can write a full explanation why your code works as it works and not as you expect.

Comment: sorry for the delay guys, I had to run to go to home after work, Ok. @MichałRybak the only code in layout.html.twig is `{# src/Blogger/BlogBundle/Resources/views/layout.html.twig #}
{% extends '::base.html.twig' %}

{% block sidebar %}
    Sidebar content
{% endblock %}` because, it extends the base template which is http://pastebin.com/skTTnjEF

Comment: @LaurentWartel Just WOW. You have just gotten rid of 50% of my concern, but sadly, when I refresh the page, there is that link again. So, now what is left is how to keep it permanently removed.

Comment: @MichałRybak You also, you have been super helpful, I forgot to tag your name, before my above answer, and now I can not edit it.

Comment: To keep it permanently removed, just check if session exists before displaying it. There are `{% if (...) %}` tags in Twig.

Comment: You can do it like [this](http://pastebin.com/NjjR2jdA), but you need `session_exists` variable. To set it, simply check if session exists in your controller and add appropriate value to the returned array.

Comment: I am getting `Variable "session_exists" does not exist` when I used your approach @MichałRybak but even with that method, the session is getting created everytime I load a page, not sure what the problem is,

Comment: Yes, because you need to change your controller code - just check if session value is null and pass the parameter to template. Take a look at [this](http://pastebin.com/AFN43FMB)

Comment: And if you don't want to create new session every time, just get the existing one: [link](http://pastebin.com/C5ZVGJDx)

Comment: There is something very strange here, because when I use your code, I can not see "Session doesn't exist." message, but by default, the request is passing through the HelloWorld controller, in which the session is getting set, so there should be a session that is set, when you browse the page... say the first time. I think, the problem is almost solved, but this is strange thing to just pass by

Comment: @Xaltra, session doesn't work the way you think it works.
Think of the session as about a big array with key-value pairs. This 'array' always exists. What do *we* do with session, is putting something *inside* this array (this is done with `$session->set(key, value);`). What my code does is to check if session contains pair with key 'name'. It clearly doesn't, because you don't set it in your code.  This is why you always see "Session doesn't exist".

Comment: Yes, I know that @MichałRybak In-fact, I manage sessions very well, using pure php functions, but in this case, when the php runs through the controller, it should reach the place in which, session is being set by default. But, instead it says session is not found. Just don't get that.

Comment: *Nowhere* in your controller you set the session. There is simply *no call* to `$session->set();`.

Comment: I wrote it by hand and without checking, but I hope it works: [html](http://pastebin.com/nuyFeA8e) , [routing](http://pastebin.com/eaFWjFh2) ,  [controller](http://pastebin.com/d962HwMw).
This adds new controller that allows to set session variable 'name' to John. I also added displaying current name value and removed unnecessary code. Please analyse it carefully to understand how this works. My job is done here :)

Comment: Hmm, interesting. I will check this out in a while.

Comment: While, I still have problems I will just chose the end the question here. Thanks @MichałRybak