# How to make/handle AJAX requests in Symfony 2

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, symfony, twig

I have a set of sessions in a page, which I want to remove using AJAX. i.e click on a link, and without having to navigate for a new page, just remove the session, and show a message on success.

Someone suggested this approach, but I can't seem to get the sessions removed, neither get a any success/failure messages.

**Example controller:**

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;

// ...

public function ajaxRemoveSessionAction()
{
    // Destroy the desired session
    $session = $this->getRequest()->getSession();
    $session->remove('name');

    return new JsonResponse(array('success' => true));
}
```

**Example routing:**

```
ajax_remove_session:
    pattern:  /remove-session
    defaults: { _controller: FooTestBundle:Page:ajaxRemoveSession }
```

**Example twig:**

```
<a href="#" id="remove_session">Remove session</a>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#remove_session').click(function(){
        event.preventDefault();

        $.ajax({
          url: {{ url('ajax_remove_session') }},
          cache: false,
          success: function(html){
            // do something on success
          }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```

These are just examples need testing.

Comment: Are you trying to destroy other users sessions or your own or something else entirely?

Comment: The session is deleted successfully, only you do not see it because the browser caches the results.
You can see that the session has been eliminated by simply refresh the page and checking the profiler.

Comment: @Lughino OK, I will take your word for it, but why am I not getting the response message? AJAX should return a response message, which is in the controller, through the `reponseText` property. So, what should I do to see this message?

Comment: @Chausser I am trying to get rid of the `name` session only.

Comment: Its possible that for some reason the ajax response is failing. Add .fail(function(event){console.log(event)}) like $.ajax(...).fail(); This way you can get more info about the request.

Comment: @Chausser Do you know, where I should put the code? sorry, I am new to Js/jQuery

Comment: Check this pastebin i just updated your script you have above http://pastebin.com/x2iH9YQS

Comment: @Chausser I appreciate your help really. This issue is driving me crazy for three days in a row, but it is still not fixed. You can see the image I uploaded here: http://imm.io/1ivEt I don't know what is happening. All, scripts are pasted here, I am sure I am forgetting something, just can't spot it.

Comment: As rightly said @Chausser put the method fail to see that the ajax call returns error you! I'm going to trial anyway .. did you remember to put the controller `use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\JsonResponse;`?  Enter the code line that returns the error! Here you can see the correct syntax for an ajax call: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: @Lughino Thank you for helping, but Yes! I have the `JsonResponse` object, as you can see here: http://pastebin.com/8egWHzDa 

This whole thing, is making me doubt, if doing AJAX is even possible with Symfony :)

Comment: I use ajax calls in a lot of my symfony projects with no problem. i know your example doesnt show it but if you are posting data to the action and then using symfony forms to validate the data you are likely getting a csrf_protection error. You really just need to find out what is coming back from symfony hence the .fail() addition.

Comment: @Chausser The weird thing is that, I am not using any forms, it is just a link, and based on a session i.e. `echo "<a href=".$_SESSION['link']."> remove link</a>";` and when that is clicked, the controller is supposed to delete the session. that is it. I don't know, any simple script than that.

Comment: what version of php and what version of symfony are you using?

Comment: I am using php 5.4 and latest version of symfony. 2.3.6

Comment: @Chausser Added `+100` bounty to my similar question, you may be interest to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355562/how-to-add-ajax-capabilites-to-symfony out.

Comment: @Lughino  Added `+100` bounty to my similar question, you may be interest to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355562/how-to-add-ajax-capabilites-to-symfony out.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check your JavaScript console? It doesn't look like you're outputting valid JavaScript

This bit here

```
$.ajax({
  url: {{ url('ajax_remove_session') }},
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    // do something on success
  }
});
```

Would end up looking like this

```
$.ajax({
  url: /remove-session,
  cache: false,
  success: function(html){
    // do something on success
  }
});
```

See the bug? The url is not delimited

You can fix this in one of two ways

1. Put in the delimiters yourself

   ```
   url: "{{ url('ajax_remove_session') }}",
   ```
2. Let Twig do it for you

   ```
   url: {{ url('ajax_remove_session')|json_encode|raw }},
   ```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but the session is still not getting removed. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: I Added `+100` bounty to my similar question, you may be interest to check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19355562/how-to-add-ajax-capabilites-to-symfony out.